# Why show java.lang.ClassCastException: android.text.SpannableString cannot be cast to java.lang.String?

Tags: java, android, string, clipboard, spannablestring

When copying `String` from any browser page, `pasteData` works properly.
However when copying `SpannedString` from a message sent item editor(field), the application crashes and shows this error message:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.text.SpannableString cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

My code:

```
// since the clipboard contains plain text.
ClipData.Item item = clipBoard.getPrimaryClip().getItemAt(0);

// Gets the clipboard as text.
String pasteData = new String();
pasteData = (String) item.getText();
```

where the `ClipboardManager` instance defined as `clipBoard`, below:

```
clipBoard = (ClipboardManager) context.getSystemService(context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
clipBoard.addPrimaryClipChangedListener(new ClipboardListener());
```

All I'm trying to do is use `pasteData` in `String` format.
How to get rid of this error?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

SpannableString is not String directly. so, you can not cast. but, it can be converted to string. you can convert something to string with concatenating with empty string.

```
pasteData = "" + item.getText();
```

Comment: Code-only answer is discouraged since it might confuse OP and future readers. Instead, explain what the code does.

Comment: This is a work around, and does not address the root problem. The problem is that item.getText() returns a CharSequence, not a String. OP should use item.getText().toString() to convert the CharSequence to String

Answer (score 38):

From [CharSequence.toString()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/CharSequence.html#toString())

> Returns a string with the same characters in the same order as in this sequence.

You need to use next code.

```
String pasteData = item.getText().toString();
```

You can not cast to `android.text.SpannableString` because `item.getText()` returns `CharSequence`, there are a lot of implementations of [it](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/CharSequence.html)

Comment: Gem of an answer. Sounds trivial but saves a lot of headache. Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

This is what it worked for me in `Kotlin`:

```
val str = text.toString()
```

Answer (score 2):

If your Spanned text only containing HTML content then you can convert it using `Html.toHtml()`

```
String htmlString = Html.toHtml(spannedText);
```

Answer (score 0):

It has worked for me
     `String htmlString = String.valueOf(Html.fromHtml(contenttext,Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));`

Answer (score 0):

You want to add attribute in Textview in xml file like this

add this ->  android:bufferType="spannable"

example:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/self_assessment_intro2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:bufferType="spannable"
        android:text="@string/self_assessment_intro2"
        android:textSize="@dimen/self_assessment_intro_text_size" />
```

Answer (score 0):

if using edittext don't forget to add like this when getting the data

`binding.edittext.text.toString()`